# Rails 4 app on Heroku is 500ing, but no error message in logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I've made a new Rails 4 beta app and deployed it to Heroku (using Ruby 2.0.0, and Unicorn via a Procfile).

It runs fine locally with `foreman start`, but when I visit the homepage of the deployed app, I just get the standard Heroku 500 error:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

However, in the logs, **there are no errors**. I've no idea what is causing the 500.

Here is the output from my last `git push heroku master`:

```
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 656 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Using rake (10.0.4)
       Using i18n (0.6.4)
       Using minitest (4.7.3)
       Using multi_json (1.7.2)
       Using atomic (1.1.8)
       Using thread_safe (0.1.0)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
       Using activesupport (4.0.0.beta1)
       Using builder (3.1.4)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using rack (1.5.2)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using actionpack (4.0.0.beta1)
       Using mime-types (1.23)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using treetop (1.4.12)
       Using mail (2.5.3)
       Using actionmailer (4.0.0.beta1)
       Using activemodel (4.0.0.beta1)
       Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (0.0.3)
       Using arel (4.0.0)
       Using activerecord (4.0.0.beta1)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
       Using execjs (1.4.0)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using json (1.7.7)
       Using rdoc (3.12.2)
       Using thor (0.18.1)
       Using railties (4.0.0.beta1)
       Using coffee-rails (4.0.0)
       Using hike (1.2.2)
       Using jbuilder (1.0.2)
       Using jquery-rails (2.2.1)
       Using kgio (2.8.0)
       Using mysql2 (0.3.11)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Using tilt (1.3.7)
       Using sprockets (2.9.3)
       Using sprockets-rails (2.0.0.rc4)
       Using rails (4.0.0.beta1)
       Using raindrops (0.11.0)
       Using sass (3.2.8)
       Using sass-rails (4.0.0.rc1)
       Using turbolinks (1.1.1)
       Using uglifier (2.0.1)
       Using unicorn (4.6.2)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       I, [2013-04-23T22:28:44.559735 #871]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_33m76p0rij8a5/public/assets/rails-d8fb6a2617998f32edf5edb354fc5326.png
       I, [2013-04-23T22:28:49.911890 #871]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_33m76p0rij8a5/public/assets/application-d4a508061cd56ce9e544945495285e0c.js
       I, [2013-04-23T22:28:50.120141 #871]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_33m76p0rij8a5/public/assets/application-a3b89b66a8471f3e75abb239e3b35c7d.css
       Asset precompilation completed (8.30s)
-----> Rails plugin injection
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types      -> web
       Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, worker

-----> Compiled slug size: 35.0MB
-----> Launching... done, v21
       http://blofs.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:blofs.git
   32e51a2..37d989c  master -> master
```

And here are the logs from that push:

```
2013-04-23T22:28:06.650049+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-04-23T22:29:11.194613+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v21 created by callum.locke@gmail.com
2013-04-23T22:29:11.365908+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 37d989c by callum.locke@gmail.com
2013-04-23T22:29:11.441066+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-04-23T22:29:11.932952+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-04-23T22:29:12.858139+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-04-23T22:29:13.194707+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-04-23T22:29:13.194495 #2]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 5 exit 0> worker=0
2013-04-23T22:29:13.194902+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-04-23T22:29:13.194747 #2]  INFO -- : master complete
2013-04-23T22:29:14.312014+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2013-04-23T22:29:14.338943+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 25281 -E $RACK_ENV`
2013-04-23T22:29:15.717687+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-04-23T22:29:15.717387 #2]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:25281 fd=7
2013-04-23T22:29:15.717916+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-04-23T22:29:15.717861 #2]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
2013-04-23T22:29:15.721526+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-04-23T22:29:15.721385 #2]  INFO -- : master process ready
2013-04-23T22:29:15.723623+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-04-23T22:29:15.723389 #5]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=5
2013-04-23T22:29:15.723805+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-04-23T22:29:15.723750 #5]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
2013-04-23T22:29:16.305653+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-04-23T22:29:16.891063+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-04-23T22:29:16.890882 #5]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
```

After that, I tried to load the homepage in my browser, and these are the only two extra lines that appeared in the logs:

```
2013-04-23T22:29:26.685651+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=blofs.herokuapp.com fwd="46.65.16.44" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=156ms status=500 bytes=706
2013-04-23T22:29:26.973073+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=blofs.herokuapp.com fwd="46.65.16.44" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=0
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Other things that might be relevant:

- I've disabled the standard Heroku Postgres addon and am using the ClearDB MySQL addon instead.
- I've tried manually changing the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable from the previous value (which was still the postgres URL even after I removed the postgres addon) to the same value as the `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL` var (the mysql one). This didn't seem to make any difference.
- I have added `ruby '2.0.0'` to my Gemfile, and added `mysql2` and `unicorn` gems. And I've used the `config/unicorn.rb` suggested at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn
- My Procfile only contains: `web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -E $RACK_ENV`
- It works fine locally with `foreman start`.
- Other than the modifications described above, it's basically an out-of-the-box app created with `rails new`.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have the heroku rails 4 gems.   See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to add `gem 'rails_12factor'` to your Gemfile. It's a <s>temporary</s> fix from Heroku to make Rails 4+ work with their service.

See [Getting Started with Rails 4.x on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4-getting-started) or [Getting Started with Rails 5.x on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5).

Comment: You should accept this answer as it is most likely the key to solving your problem.

Comment: Make sure to change `config.log_level = :debug` in your production.rb for full debug logs.

Comment: This work for me! I firstly add that gem and then I got a more detailed log error. I then run `heroku run rake db:migrate` and after this the app was working!

Comment: It must not be very temporary. I just created a new rails app, pushed to heroku, and was getting the same issue (empty logs). Adding `rails_12factor` solved it.

Answer (score 1):

These answers tell you how to turn on logs so you can look for the error, but don't really answer the question, 'What *might* be going wrong?'

Apart from the suggestions in the answer by @Lauren to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410811/how-do-you-diagnose-a-500-error-on-heroku-when-there-is-no-error-message-in-the), here's another possibility - if you attempt to access the `ENV` constant in your production environment and have not set it via `heroku config:set`, that will also cause a very silent 500 error.