# Heroku | Rails | Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, server, subdomain

So I was trying to deploying my application to heroku, It built correctly but when I tried to access it. 
It responds with:
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

So I checked the Logs and the logs were empty...

So I tried replicating the same command that heroku uses to run my application:

> rails s -p 41616 -b lvh.me -e production

and so it boots on my computer, you can check how the server load [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmMae.png)

but I still got the same error, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t1nt.png)
the error code that I receive is:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Now earlier version of this software was deployable to heroku and worked great. The major change in this push was I added subdomains to my heroku application. Don't know if that caused it

Any idea what might be the reason?

[Solved]  problem solved by LMo answear in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410811/how-do-you-diagnose-a-500-error-on-heroku-when-there-is-no-error-message-in-the)

steps :

> heroku run rake db:migrate

And add the following gem to your gem file

```
 gem 'rails_12factor'
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

On your local, when you refresh the page in browser there should be some exception shown in the console where you started `rails s....`

The error would point you towards the issue on local. Maybe you don't have production db setup on local.

Similary, do this to tail log on heroku to see error when you refresh heroku url in browser:

```
heroku logs --tail
```

More details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Answer (score 1):

Add a logging add-on such as PaperTrail (free) and then see what the logs say. If you've done that and it's empty, then go to the app's dashboard, go to the activity tab, then find the latest deployment and click the 'log' button. You should see the error message in there.

Answer (score 0):

[Solved] problem solved by LMo answear in this post

steps :

heroku run rake db:migrate
And add the following gem to your gem file

gem 'rails_12factor'
Thanks for help