# I get no log message from django running heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn

I'm running a Django site on Heroku, and the server returns a 500 error, but no reason why.

All I get from heroku logs is this message:

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/accounts/login/"
host=dagenssalg.herokuapp.com request_id=02ec11bf-ea26-4f98-
ab5a-270147167d42 fwd="87.57.162.154" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms 
service=29ms status=500 bytes=234 protocol=https
```

DEBUG is set to false:

```
DEBUG = False
```

Is there any way to display the detail of the error?

EDIT:

Using the LogEntries app as this question: [How do you diagnose a 500 error on Heroku when there is no error message in the logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410811/how-do-you-diagnose-a-500-error-on-heroku-when-there-is-no-error-message-in-the) sugests doesn't change anything as it grabs the same log as Heroku logs.

My app runs on Gunicorn with this Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn dagenssalg.wsgi --log-file -
```

Is there any way to instruct Gunicorn where to send the error log?

Best regards Kresten

Comment: Use [sentry](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/sentry).

Comment: Django should send an error email to `settings.ADMINS`  when there's an unhandled exception while serving a request (and log the error too). Check your `settings.LOGGING`  conf (cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/#configuring-logging)

Comment: I don't have Django logging setup now, I'll try that. But if the server gives a 500 error, would you not look for the log in the servers error log and not in Djangos log?