# Page not displaying on heroku - heroku[router]: status = 500

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Could one advise me on how to correct this error, i have no clue and i have tried all helps from other pages on stackoverflow.

i have tried all the below recommended suggestions by others:

- [suggestion1: log entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410811/how-do-you-diagnose-a-500-error-on-heroku-when-there-is-no-error-message-in-the)
- [gem 'rails_12factor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179995/rails-4-app-on-heroku-is-500ing-but-no-error-message-in-logs)
- changing `config.log_level = :debug`
- `rake db:migrate`
- `heroku config:set`

but i am unsure why i get the below error. Your help and advise would be much appreciated.

error message in console:

```
2018-06-05T16:57:24.444942+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/adverts/product-manager" host=www.africanjober.com request_id=f4308437-df4b-435e-a4d9-ee4080c86de9 fwd="178.239.106.244" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=29ms status=500 bytes=1754 protocol=http
2018-06-05T16:57:24.674917+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.africanjober.com request_id=7d28bd15-a173-4a7f-8f0d-79bb5ebddadd fwd="178.239.106.244" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=133 protocol=http
```

complete console message:

```
018-06-05T16:57:24.443367+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:484:in `create_or_update'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443369+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443371+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443373+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:552:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443374+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:502:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443376+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443377+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443379+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:103:in `save'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443381+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443382+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443383+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in save'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443385+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443387+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `block in transaction'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443395+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `within_new_transaction'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443397+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `transaction'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443398+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443400+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443402+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block in save'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443404+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:283:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443406+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:267:in `save'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443407+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:34:in `create'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443409+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/impressionist-1.6.1/app/controllers/impressionist_controller.rb:45:in `impressionist_subapp_filter'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443411+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/impressionist-1.6.1/app/controllers/impressionist_controller.rb:9:in `block in impressionist'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443412+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:445:in `instance_exec'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443414+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:445:in `block in make_lambda'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443416+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:161:in `block in halting'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443418+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:501:in `block in call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443420+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:501:in `each'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443422+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:501:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443423+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:495:in `block (2 levels) in around'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443425+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:306:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443427+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/public_activity-1.5.0/lib/public_activity/utility/store_controller.rb:25:in `store_controller_for_public_activity'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443429+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `block in make_lambda'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443430+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:305:in `block in halting'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443432+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:494:in `block in around'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443434+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:502:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443436+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443437+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443439+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443440+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443442+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443444+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443445+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443447+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443449+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443451+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443454+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443452+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443462+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443464+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443466+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443468+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443469+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443471+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443473+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443475+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443476+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:692:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443478+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443480+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443482+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443483+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443485+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443487+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443488+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443490+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443492+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443493+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443495+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:562:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443497+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443498+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443500+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443501+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443505+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443503+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443507+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443509+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443511+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443512+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443514+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443516+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443518+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443520+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443521+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443523+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443525+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443527+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443530+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443528+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443531+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443538+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443540+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443542+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443544+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443545+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443547+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443549+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443551+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-06-05T16:57:24.443552+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-06-05T16:57:24.444942+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/adverts/product-manager" host=www.africanjober.com request_id=f4308437-df4b-435e-a4d9-ee4080c86de9 fwd="178.239.106.244" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=29ms status=500 bytes=1754 protocol=http
2018-06-05T16:57:24.674917+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.africanjober.com request_id=7d28bd15-a173-4a7f-8f0d-79bb5ebddadd fwd="178.239.106.244" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=133 protocol=http
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be a database error which typically happens when you only run migrations on your local and forget to run migrations on the heroku 
 box. Run

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

to run migrations on your deployed box after you've pushed your latest git commit to it.

Comment: when i run `heroku run rake db:migrate` i get this `ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (3.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"` and still get the same error

Comment: Can you add the console output when you type: 'rails routes' in console?

Comment: thank you bkunzi01, this was certainly to do with the database, i did not need to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` but i needed to upgrade my database with heroku

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. Thank you to everyone

- This was due to restricted access to the database using heroku.
- I was on the heroku DATABASE_URL which permitted a maximum on 10'000 rows of code. i had 10'891 rows of code
- to find out more on your pg database, type: `heroku pg:info --app yourAppName`
- i had to upgrade [in the admin panel] to HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD_URL or you can simply type in the terminal `heroku pg:upgrade HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD --app yourAppName`
- before you upgrade ensure maintenance is on. in the terminal type: `heroku maintenance:on`
- new database url i selected is currently $9/mth - this permits more rows of code
- once you've upgraded in the terminal, type: `heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD` to set it as the default database
- if you currently have data stored in the previous, type: `heroku pg:copy DATABASE_URL HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD --app yourAppName` to transfer data

for more detailed info checkout this link: [upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases)